# How to transform set of fields inside an objects in javascript and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, react-native, data-structures

I have a following object in `React`:

```
const userData = 
  {
    id: 30,
    firstName: "James",
    lastName: "Anderson",
    programmingLanguage: "Java, Python",              # HERE
    LanguageSpoken: "French, German, English",        # HERE
    Nationality: "French",
    Hobby: "Developer, Hiking"                        # HERE
  },
]
```

what would be the best way to loop through this object and transform the 3 fields `programmingLanguage` , `LanguageSpoken`  and `Hobby` , which types are `string` into a **List (type) of string**.

so after the transformation, it should look like these.

```
const userData = 
  {
    id: 30,
    firstName: "James",
    lastName: "Anderson",
    programmingLanguage: ["Java", "Python"],         # List of strings
    LanguageSpoken: ["French", "German", "English"], # List of strings
    Nationality: "French",
    Hobby: ["Developer", "Hiking"]                   # List of strings         
  },
]
```

PS: **(I know it suck)** but the format above is the way i am receiving the data from the backend and because i am not allowed to change that i have to deal with it.

If it was for a single field I would have done this:

```
  const transformedField = userData.programmingLanguage.toString().split(",");
  const resultTransformedField = transformedField.map((i) => Number(i));

  const newDataUser = {
    ...useData,
    programmingLanguage: resultTransformedField,
  };
```

but as mentioned above i have to modify 3 fields.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd map each object to a new object with `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
const properties = ['programmingLanguage', 'LanguageSpoken', 'Hobby'];

const userData = [
  {
    id: 30,
    firstName: "James",
    lastName: "Anderson",
    programmingLanguage: "Java, Python",
    LanguageSpoken: "French, German, English",
    Nationality: "French",
    Hobby: "Developer, Hiking"
  },
];

const output = userData.map(
  obj => Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).map(
      ([key, val]) => [key, properties.includes(key) ? val.split(', ') : val]
    )
  )
);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: I see more and more uses for a built-in function that does nothing more than `(obj, fn) => Object .fromEntries ( Object.entries (obj) .flatMap (([k, v]) => fn (k, v)))`  Here it would then be `Object .rebuild (userData, (key, value) => [[key, properies.includes (key) ? val.split(', ') : val)]])`.  (The array of results from the callback allows for splitting or filtering of the input and not just one-to-one results.)  I think it is really time at least to add this to Ramda. [For instance](http://fourwindssoft.com/link/13).